# How to fix 'You cannot call create unless the parent is saved' error when trying to upload images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When I try to upload an image to my rails app, I check whether it's below 3 mega pixels and remove if it's below the value. If the image is above 3MP it works. But if it's below 3mp, it gives me this error `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`

The photo create function :

```
def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(file: params[:file])
    if @photo.save!(:validate => false)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json{ render :json => @photo }
        end
    end
end
```

The check mega pixel function :

```
after_create :check_mp
before_save :set_mrdocs_rejects
before_create :new_workflow_state
validates :title, :description, :category_id, :tag_list, presence: true
before_save :custom_corrections
after_save :accept_or_reject, :submit_photo
validate :custom_validations

def check_mp
    @min_mp = Setting.find_by_key('min_megapixel').value.to_i
    @mp = ((self.width * self.height) / 1000000.0).round
    if @mp < @min_mp
        rejected = self.user.rejected
        rejected << self.originalname
        self.user.update_attribute(:rejected, rejected)

        self.destroy
    end
end
```

What might be causing the error?

Comment: try return false. and don't if @object.save! just save. and then shouldn't this validation be in the photo model?

Comment: yes this is in the photo model

Comment: paste the log from the console...